# Changing router WAN IP Address

Tags: networking, ip, router, wide-area-network, static-ip

Hi I don't really understand how WAN IPs work, can someone explain how I can change my address to a static one. How can I know if the address I want is taken? How can I see what addresses are available?

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need to work with your ISP/WAN provider. Start with their documentation and your contract, and contact their tech support if you're not sure what something means. They may decide that your questions actually need paid professional services, so be prepared for that.